# SQL Server 2014 always goes down every midnight (12 AM)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

We have an SQL Server 2014 with a lot of Jobs that are scheduled every 12AM. They are around 70-80 jobs that will run at 12 AM. All jobs run successfully, then we just noticed that we can no longer access the SQL server on a client workstation, nor telnet the port of the SQL. The services are still running but when we try to restart the SQL Service, it does not restart successfully. The only way to make this work again is to restart the server.

This is now happening for 3 days straight and we cannot isolate what may be causing this.

We have checked all the logs in SQL and even the event logs of the windows but there is nothing to show about any error that may cause this.

There is no any scheduled task outside SQL Job that are scheduled at midnight.

Hope you can help me as this is a big issue on us since this is a production server and we cannot avail to have the server to restart every day.

Comment: Suggestion: disable all the jobs and see if that eliminates the problem. If it does, you know it's one or more of the jobs. Next night, enable half the jobs, then the other half until you zero in on the offending job(s). Alternatively, stagger the jobs over the night, having one start every five minutes over several hours to see if you can identify when the server is crashing... or if merely staggering the jobs solves your problem.

Comment: I tried to clone the exact server (since it is a VM) and run all the jobs at the same time, but I did not reproduce the problem in the clone VM. I did that by adjusting the time to 12 AM to run all the jobs on the specified schedule.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem?